# Images from one record are not updated in other images correctly

Tags: php, laravel

When I update the images in a registry, the old images are not deleted, but are kept together with the new images. I don't want this type of behavior, how can I delete these old images to store new ones in a registry? `avatar_students` receives `student_id` from the `students` table record to identify student images.

```
public function update(StudentRequest $request, $id)
{

    $student = StudentModel::findOrFail($id);
    $validations = $request->validated();

    if ($request->hasFile('image_student')) {
        
        AvatarStudentModel::where('student_id', $id)->delete();
        
        $images_paths = [];

        foreach ($request->file('image_student') as $image) {

            $original_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image_path = $image->storeAs("avatars/$id", $original_name);

            AvatarStudentModel::create([
                'student_id' => $id,
                'image' => $image_path,
            ]);

            $images_paths[] = $image_path;
        }
    }

    $student->update($validations);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the updated code, I've made sure that you use the `AvatarStudentModel` consistently for both deleting old images and creating new records. This should resolve the issue of old images not being deleted correctly when updating the student's images.

```
public function update(StudentRequest $request, $id)
{
    $student = StudentModel::findOrFail($id);
    $validations = $request->validated();

    if ($request->hasFile('image_student')) {
        // Delete the old images associated with the student
        AvatarStudentModel::where('student_id', $id)->delete();
        
        $images_paths = [];

        foreach ($request->file('image_student') as $image) {
            $original_name = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $image_path = $image->storeAs("avatars/$id", $original_name);

            // Use the same model to create records
            AvatarStudentModel::create([
                'student_id' => $id,
                'image' => $image_path,
            ]);

            $images_paths[] = $image_path;
        }
    }

    $student->update($validations);
}
```

Comment: It was my wrong, however continue doesn't working.